# CSS position child under it's parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to position child element (C) under its parent (B), and above B's neighbor (C)?

It's a little bit difficult to describe, you can watch example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPzF/).

The question is to position blue `div.inner` above red `div.neighbor`  AND under green `div.outer`.

To illustrate:

[image]

HTML code:

```
 <div class="neighbor">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.neighbor{
background-color: red;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;    
}

.outer{
background-color: green;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;    
}

.inner{
background-color: blue; 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
left:250px;    
}
```

Comment: Could you provied an image which shows what you are trying to reach?

Comment: To position blue div above red one AND under green one http://tinypic.com/r/2drbfk0/5

Comment: is this what you want? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPzF/3/).

Answer (score 2):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Ff2DM/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: You're assuming he wants a fixed position value, which isn't always the case!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.neighboor {
        background-color: red;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:-200;
    }

    .outer {
        background-color: green;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

    .inner {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position:relative;
        z-index: -100;
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;
    }
```